# Cannot Access Docker Containers over Network

Tags: ubuntu, docker, proxmox

Having some issues accessing Docker containers on my network. Server software stack:

- Proxmox VE
- Ubuntu 22.04
- Jellyfin (Web UI works)
- Portainer (Web UI doesn't work)
- QBittorrent (Web UI doesn't work)

Docker Images Used:

- lscr.io/linuxserver/qbittorrent:latest
- jellyfin/jellyfin:latest
- portainer/portainer-ce:latest

Installations were successful, used docker-compose.yml files for jellyfin and qbittorrent. Can access Jellyfin on port 8096. Qbittorrent and Portainer will timeout when trying to access them through Chrome with [IP]:8080 or [IP]:8000. 
Port mappings for Portainer:

- 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp, :::9000->9000/tcp, 9443/tcp

Port mappings for Qbittorrent:

- 0.0.0.0:6881->6881/tcp, :::6881->6881/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp

Jellyfin did not have any mappings listed under `docker container ls`. UFW is set to inactive, do I need to configure port forwarding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up wiping the VM and starting over as I hadn't made any progress with this. My guess as to why this occurred was changing a DNS setting (using 8.8.8.8) but I'm not 100%. All the containers that I need now work correctly with Portainer.